# Gramps' Prolog Export Function: fancy filter or statistical tool?

Tags: gramps, statistics

Gramps is one of the most widely used genealogy program as far as I know and has recently seen another addition to its wide array of export features, called prolog as announced [here](https://gramps-project.org/2015/05/using-prolog-to-analyze-your-family-tree/).

Can someone show a more advanced use of prolog in combination with a family tree? Is it a fancy way to filter ones family tree? Or is it possible to conduct statistics with it? What else could be done with prolog and my family tree to enrich my understanding of the genealogical data at hand?

It sounds interesting but I have not understood why a general genealogist would want/need this. Any explanation and enlightenment is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a sophisticated method to explore your tree. Prolog is great for asking questions like those in the blog post. It is very powerful, and can concisely represent complex ideas. But it isn't very good at doing stats or general queries.

If one knew the power of Prolog, then you could apply those ideas to a tree. Probably only useful for special-purpose queries, such as "who has a mother who has the same surname as their father's mother?"... or something equally crazy.

Comment: Thanks, Doug, for your quick reply. Do you have any idea if someone else has used prolog for "crazy" queries as mentioned in your answer and published them? I would like to see more in action.

Comment: No, but someone familiar with Prolog could suggest some. You might find additional ideas in a Prolog textbook. I'm an academic, and if this were my area, there is probably an interesting paper here...